# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json, geojson, folium

buenas tardes.

Estoy teniendo problemas para crear un choropleth en base a un GeoJson file, creo que el error está en el valor Key_on, ya que cuando comento este campo obtengo el mapa pero con las zonas del Json file en negro. Dejo unas lineas del Geojson file y mi query. Agradezco si alguien puede ayudarme. Saludos

Mi query:

```
mvd_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=mvd_geojson,
    data=mvd_merged_final,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Avg Usd/m2'],
    key_on = 'features.properties.id_barrio',
    fill_color='RdPu', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='House Sales Price in Montevideo',
    highlight=True
)
markers_colors = []
for lat, lon, poi, cluster in zip(mvd_merged_notnan['Latitud'], mvd_merged_notnan['Longitud'], mvd_merged_notnan['Neighborhood'], mvd_merged_notnan['Cluster Labels']):
    label = folium.Popup(str(poi) + ' Cluster ' + str(cluster), parse_html=True)
    folium.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lon],
        radius=5,
        popup=label,
        color=rainbow[int(cluster)-1],
        fill=True,
        fill_color=rainbow[int(cluster)-1],
        fill_opacity=0.7).add_to(mvd_map)
   
#Show map
mvd_map
```

Ejemplo GeoJson file:

```
mvd_geojson={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id_barrio": 32, "nombre": "MANGA TOLEDO CHICO", "codigo": "MT" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -56.087509, -34.779000 ], [ -56.089275, -34.780357 ], [ -56.097165, -34.784546 ], [ -56.100819, -34.786404 ], [ -56.101924, -34.786965 ], [ -56.107073, -34.789582 ], [ -56.108435, -34.789457 ], [ -56.108794, -34.789425 ], [ -56.117839, -34.793944 ], [ -56.117866, -34.794173 ], [ -56.120106, -34.798928 ], [ -56.120258, -34.799004 ], [ -56.120684, -34.799386 ], [ -56.122132, -34.800086 ], [ -56.122818, -34.800413 ], [ -56.122992, -34.800499 ], [ -56.123437, -34.800709 ], [ -56.125085, -34.801503 ], [ -56.126321, -34.800022 ], [ -56.127398, -34.798726 ], [ -56.127432, -34.798650 ], [ -56.129320, -34.798735 ], [ -56.136071, -34.799661 ], [ -56.136157, -34.799733 ], [ -56.136366, -34.800431 ], [ -56.136341, -34.799954 ], [ -56.136435, -34.799778 ], [ -56.143931, -34.800882 ], [ -56.143303, -34.803682 ], [ -56.143246, -34.803673 ], [ -56.142783, -34.806054 ], [ -56.143128, -34.806094 ], [ -56.144617, -34.806293 ], [ -56.147514, -34.806678 ], [ -56.148977, -34.806872 ], [ -56.155225, -34.807668 ], [ -56.155363, -34.807686 ], [ -56.160480, -34.808367 ], [ -56.160643, -34.808380 ], [ -56.161442, -34.808445 ], [ -56.164497, -34.808874 ], [ -56.167687, -34.811953 ], [ -56.167929, -34.812200 ], [ -56.169353, -34.813643 ], [ -56.169992, -34.814246 ], [ -56.171041, -34.815230 ], [ -56.172770, -34.816857 ], [ -56.174489, -34.818542 ], [ -56.175799, -34.819787 ], [ -56.177607, -34.821648 ], [ -56.177726, -34.821769 ], [ -56.179700, -34.823801 ], [ -56.181240, -34.825329 ], [ -56.183429, -34.827478 ], [ -56.183562, -34.827428 ], [ -56.183787, -34.827355 ], [ -56.184119, -34.827349 ], [ -56.184351, -34.827245 ], [ -56.185070, -34.826765 ], [ -56.185450, -34.826034 ], [ -56.185098, -34.825003 ], [ -56.185391, -34.824430 ], [ -56.185336, -34.823840 ], [ -56.185281, -34.823258 ], [ -56.185901, -34.822892 ], [ -56.186394, -34.822719 ], [ -56.186814, -34.822510 ], [ -56.187035, -34.822420 ], [ -56.187150, -34.822230 ], [ -56.187539, -34.822031 ], [ -56.187831, -34.821354 ], [ -56.187457, -34.820156 ], [ -56.187749, -34.819493 ], [ -56.187810, -34.818956 ], [ -56.187176, -34.818331 ], [ -56.186983, -34.817449 ], [ -56.186917, -34.817259 ], [ -56.186607, -34.816729 ], [ -56.186029, -34.816257 ], [ -56.185843, -34.816068 ], [ -56.185677, -34.815627 ], [ -56.185593, -34.815343 ], [ -56.185572, -34.815037 ], [ -56.185591, -34.814766 ], [ -56.185405, -34.814393 ], [ -56.185465, -34.814154 ], [ -56.185382, -34.813951 ], [ -56.185566, -34.813698 ], [ -56.185483, -34.813577 ], [ -56.185749, -34.813256 ], [ -56.185851, -34.812967 ], [ -56.185602, -34.812495 ], [ -56.185273, -34.812360 ], [ -56.184944, -34.812325 ], [ -56.184676, -34.812277 ], [ -56.184225, -34.811967 ], [ -56.183687, -34.811585 ], [ -56.183449, -34.811347 ], [ -56.183459, -34.811095 ], [ -56.183642, -34.810634 ], [ -56.183724, -34.810463 ], [ -56.183640, -34.810247 ], [ -56.183619, -34.810125 ], [ -56.183762, -34.809769 ], [ -56.184048, -34.809497 ], [ -56.184274, -34.809429 ], [ -56.184562, -34.809446 ], [ -56.184849, -34.809207 ], [ -56.185157, -34.809156 ], [ -56.185567, -34.808898 ], [ -56.185669, -34.808695 ], [ -56.185504, -34.808542 ], [ -56.185297, -34.808340 ], [ -56.185070, -34.808070 ], [ -56.184987, -34.807886 ], [ -56.185048, -34.807629 ], [ -56.184945, -34.807512 ], [ -56.184554, -34.807463 ], [ -56.184265, -34.807140 ], [ -56.183955, -34.806771 ], [ -56.183687, -34.806650 ], [ -56.183276, -34.806516 ], [ -56.183069, -34.806246 ], [ -56.182822, -34.806076 ], [ -56.182718, -34.805909 ], [ -56.182696, -34.805639 ], [ -56.182798, -34.805431 ], [ -56.182900, -34.805296 ], [ -56.183147, -34.805196 ], [ -56.183496, -34.805159 ], [ -56.183742, -34.805072 ], [ -56.184133, -34.804923 ], [ -56.184176, -34.804877 ], [ -56.184244, -34.804810 ], [ -56.184480, -34.804579 ], [ -56.184521, -34.804412 ], [ -56.184294, -34.804156 ], [ -56.184004, -34.803801 ], [ -56.184004, -34.803634 ], [ -56.184065, -34.803481 ], [ -56.184434, -34.803412 ], [ -56.184825, -34.803325 ], [ -56.185091, -34.803189 ], [ -56.185295, -34.802833 ], [ -56.185582, -34.802458 ], [ -56.185847, -34.802169 ], [ -56.186093, -34.801965 ], [ -56.186277, -34.801762 ], [ -56.186317, -34.801406 ], [ -56.186501, -34.801270 ], [ -56.186643, -34.800729 ], [ -56.186436, -34.800287 ], [ -56.186476, -34.800085 ], [ -56.186187, -34.799883 ], [ -56.185858, -34.799681 ], [ -56.185857, -34.799392 ], [ -56.186020, -34.799117 ], [ -56.185855, -34.798914 ], [ -56.185813, -34.798680 ], [ -56.185606, -34.798492 ], [ -56.185297, -34.798222 ], [ -56.185049, -34.797849 ], [ -56.184903, -34.797344 ], [ -56.184888, -34.797114 ], [ -56.184816, -34.796028 ], [ -56.185204, -34.795383 ], [ -56.185903, -34.794736 ], [ -56.186837, -34.794220 ], [ -56.187850, -34.793766 ], [ -56.188158, -34.792801 ], [ -56.189013, -34.792023 ], [ -56.189634, -34.791382 ], [ -56.190646, -34.790734 ], [ -56.191191, -34.790345 ], [ -56.191188, -34.789831 ], [ -56.191498, -34.789249 ], [ -56.191261, -34.788479 ], [ -56.190790, -34.787967 ], [ -56.190477, -34.787643 ], [ -56.191174, -34.786420 ], [ -56.190859, -34.785650 ], [ -56.190778, -34.784942 ], [ -56.190462, -34.784042 ], [ -56.190615, -34.783271 ], [ -56.190845, -34.782432 ], [ -56.191467, -34.781849 ], [ -56.190996, -34.781142 ], [ -56.191146, -34.779664 ], [ -56.191145, -34.779407 ], [ -56.190674, -34.778764 ], [ -56.190592, -34.777799 ], [ -56.190588, -34.776835 ], [ -56.190564, -34.776709 ], [ -56.190428, -34.775997 ], [ -56.190114, -34.775421 ], [ -56.189332, -34.774972 ], [ -56.189330, -34.774522 ], [ -56.188471, -34.774393 ], [ -56.188156, -34.773561 ], [ -56.188153, -34.772785 ], [ -56.188616, -34.771756 ], [ -56.189550, -34.771046 ], [ -56.191027, -34.769947 ], [ -56.191883, -34.769300 ], [ -56.192816, -34.768653 ], [ -56.193827, -34.768073 ], [ -56.193668, -34.767235 ], [ -56.193040, -34.766335 ], [ -56.192261, -34.766468 ], [ -56.191475, -34.765182 ], [ -56.191472, -34.764474 ], [ -56.190922, -34.763448 ], [ -56.189906, -34.763063 ], [ -56.188737, -34.763260 ], [ -56.187959, -34.763583 ], [ -56.187104, -34.764293 ], [ -56.185934, -34.764296 ], [ -56.185075, -34.764041 ], [ -56.184216, -34.763787 ], [ -56.183277, -34.763145 ], [ -56.182496, -34.762827 ], [ -56.181483, -34.762961 ], [ -56.181250, -34.763281 ], [ -56.180939, -34.763476 ], [ -56.180391, -34.762964 ], [ -56.179454, -34.762899 ], [ -56.178674, -34.762838 ], [ -56.178205, -34.762645 ], [ -56.178124, -34.761938 ], [ -56.177734, -34.761745 ], [ -56.178434, -34.761423 ], [ -56.178901, -34.761102 ], [ -56.178197, -34.760585 ], [ -56.178153, -34.760396 ], [ -56.177959, -34.759559 ], [ -56.178659, -34.759106 ], [ -56.179203, -34.758523 ], [ -56.179747, -34.758008 ], [ -56.179431, -34.757175 ], [ -56.179507, -34.756724 ], [ -56.179349, -34.756206 ], [ -56.178802, -34.755951 ], [ -56.178333, -34.755632 ], [ -56.177632, -34.755891 ], [ -56.176852, -34.755699 ], [ -56.176458, -34.754866 ], [ -56.177159, -34.754603 ], [ -56.176611, -34.754154 ], [ -56.176141, -34.753641 ], [ -56.175828, -34.753385 ], [ -56.175905, -34.752997 ], [ -56.175825, -34.752551 ], [ -56.175746, -34.752227 ], [ -56.175432, -34.751714 ], [ -56.175118, -34.751327 ], [ -56.174260, -34.751136 ], [ -56.173012, -34.751076 ], [ -56.172072, -34.750177 ], [ -56.171524, -34.749602 ], [ -56.171053, -34.748639 ], [ -56.171049, -34.747670 ], [ -56.171120, -34.747340 ], [ -56.171355, -34.746254 ], [ -56.171353, -34.745677 ], [ -56.171429, -34.745163 ], [ -56.170722, -34.743939 ], [ -56.169940, -34.743364 ], [ -56.168844, -34.742141 ], [ -56.168449, -34.740984 ], [ -56.168523, -34.739956 ], [ -56.168052, -34.739119 ], [ -56.167735, -34.737835 ], [ -56.168043, -34.736676 ], [ -56.167963, -34.736455 ], [ -56.167648, -34.735582 ], [ -56.167178, -34.735006 ], [ -56.166148, -34.734220 ], [ -56.166084, -34.734171 ], [ -56.165689, -34.733004 ], [ -56.162489, -34.728195 ], [ -56.159999, -34.723888 ], [ -56.155747, -34.721244 ], [ -56.148665, -34.717774 ], [ -56.148435, -34.717621 ], [ -56.143706, -34.714469 ], [ -56.140529, -34.715635 ], [ -56.135585, -34.716643 ], [ -56.132396, -34.714496 ], [ -56.126052, -34.718319 ], [ -56.124648, -34.721148 ], [ -56.123070, -34.724803 ], [ -56.122107, -34.726283 ], [ -56.121663, -34.726965 ], [ -56.128387, -34.729275 ], [ -56.126983, -34.732266 ], [ -56.128050, -34.734261 ], [ -56.125052, -34.736093 ], [ -56.121354, -34.740086 ], [ -56.121362, -34.742745 ], [ -56.121501, -34.743344 ], [ -56.121900, -34.745069 ], [ -56.119608, -34.746900 ], [ -56.116081, -34.749233 ], [ -56.112373, -34.750738 ], [ -56.109192, -34.751241 ], [ -56.108302, -34.751468 ], [ -56.106543, -34.751913 ], [ -56.103709, -34.750423 ], [ -56.101592, -34.751757 ], [ -56.100182, -34.753256 ], [ -56.098950, -34.754918 ], [ -56.098654, -34.755689 ], [ -56.098248, -34.756744 ], [ -56.096129, -34.757249 ], [ -56.094011, -34.758583 ], [ -56.094018, -34.760909 ], [ -56.096326, -34.764059 ], [ -56.099163, -34.766708 ], [ -56.098288, -34.769864 ], [ -56.097589, -34.772358 ], [ -56.095056, -34.775681 ], [ -56.094419, -34.776516 ], [ -56.091242, -34.778686 ], [ -56.087895, -34.778990 ], [ -56.087509, -34.779000 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id_barrio": 58, "nombre": "COLON SURESTE ABAYUBA", "codigo": "CY" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -56.165689, -34.733004 ], [ -56.166084, -34.734171 ], [ -56.166148, -34.734220 ], [ -56.167178, -34.735006 ], [ -56.167648, -34.735582 ], [ -56.167963, -34.736455 ], [ -56.168043, -34.736676 ], [ -56.167735, -34.737835 ], [ -56.168052, -34.739119 ], [ -56.168523, -34.739956 ], [ -56.168449, -34.740984 ], [ -56.168844, -34.742141 ], [ -56.169940, -34.743364 ], [ -56.170722, -34.743939 ], [ -56.171429, -34.745163 ], [ -56.171353, -34.745677 ], [ -56.171355, -34.746254 ], [ -56.171120, -34.747340 ], [ -56.171049, -34.747670 ], [ -56.171053, -34.748639 ], [ -56.171524, -34.749602 ], [ -56.172072, -34.750177 ], [ -56.173012, -34.751076 ], [ -56.174260, -34.751136 ], [ -56.175118, -34.751327 ], [ -56.175432, -34.751714 ], [ -56.175746, -34.752227 ], [ -56.175825, -34.752551 ], [ -56.175905, -34.752997 ], [ -56.175828, -34.753385 ], [ -56.176141, -34.753641 ], [ -56.176611, -34.754154 ], [ -56.177159, -34.754603 ], [ -56.176458, -34.754866 ], [ -56.176852, -34.755699 ], [ -56.177632, -34.755891 ], [ -56.178333, -34.755632 ], [ -56.178802, -34.755951 ], [ -56.179349, -34.756206 ], [ -56.179507, -34.756724 ], [ -56.179431, -34.757175 ], [ -56.179747, -34.758008 ], [ -56.179203, -34.758523 ], [ -56.178659, -34.759106 ], [ -56.177959, -34.759559 ], [ -56.178153, -34.760396 ], [ -56.178197, -34.760585 ], [ -56.178901, -34.761102 ], [ -56.178434, -34.761423 ], [ -56.177734, -34.761745 ], [ -56.178124, -34.761938 ], [ -56.178205, -34.762645 ], [ -56.178674, -34.762838 ], [ -56.179454, -34.762899 ], [ -56.180391, -34.762964 ], [ -56.180939, -34.763476 ], [ -56.181250, -34.763281 ], [ -56.181483, -34.762961 ], [ -56.182496, -34.762827 ], [ -56.183277, -34.763145 ], [ -56.184216, -34.763787 ], [ -56.185075, -34.764041 ], [ -56.185934, -34.764296 ], [ -56.187104, -34.764293 ], [ -56.187959, -34.763583 ], [ -56.188737, -34.763260 ], [ -56.189906, -34.763063 ], [ -56.190922, -34.763448 ], [ -56.191472, -34.764474 ], [ -56.191475, -34.765182 ], [ -56.192261, -34.766468 ], [ -56.193040, -34.766335 ], [ -56.193668, -34.767235 ], [ -56.193827, -34.768073 ], [ -56.192816, -34.768653 ], [ -56.191883, -34.769300 ], [ -56.191027, -34.769947 ], [ -56.189550, -34.771046 ], [ -56.188616, -34.771756 ], [ -56.188153, -34.772785 ], [ -56.188156, -34.773561 ], [ -56.188471, -34.774393 ], [ -56.189330, -34.774522 ], [ -56.189332, -34.774972 ], [ -56.190114, -34.775421 ], [ -56.190428, -34.775997 ], [ -56.190564, -34.776709 ], [ -56.190588, -34.776835 ], [ -56.190592, -34.777799 ], [ -56.190674, -34.778764 ], [ -56.191145, -34.779407 ], [ -56.191146, -34.779664 ], [ -56.190996, -34.781142 ], [ -56.191467, -34.781849 ], [ -56.190845, -34.782432 ], [ -56.190615, -34.783271 ], [ -56.190462, -34.784042 ], [ -56.190778, -34.784942 ], [ -56.190859, -34.785650 ], [ -56.191174, -34.786420 ], [ -56.190477, -34.787643 ], [ -56.190790, -34.787967 ], [ -56.191261, -34.788479 ], [ -56.191498, -34.789249 ], [ -56.191188, -34.789831 ], [ -56.191191, -34.790345 ], [ -56.190646, -34.790734 ], [ -56.189634, -34.791382 ], [ -56.189013, -34.792023 ], [ -56.188158, -34.792801 ], [ -56.187850, -34.793766 ], [ -56.186837, -34.794220 ], [ -56.185903, -34.794736 ], [ -56.185204, -34.795383 ], [ -56.184816, -34.796028 ], [ -56.184888, -34.797114 ], [ -56.184903, -34.797344 ], [ -56.185049, -34.797849 ], [ -56.185297, -34.798222 ], [ -56.185606, -34.798492 ], [ -56.185813, -34.798680 ], [ -56.185855, -34.798914 ], [ -56.186020, -34.799117 ], [ -56.185857, -34.799392 ], [ -56.185858, -34.799681 ], [ -56.186187, -34.799883 ], [ -56.186476, -34.800085 ], [ -56.186436, -34.800287 ], [ -56.186643, -34.800729 ], [ -56.186501, -34.801270 ], [ -56.186317, -34.801406 ], [ -56.186277, -34.801762 ], [ -56.186093, -34.801965 ], [ -56.185847, -34.802169 ], [ -56.185582, -34.802458 ], [ -56.185295, -34.802833 ], [ -56.185091, -34.803189 ], [ -56.184825, -34.803325 ], [ -56.184434, -34.803412 ], [ -56.184065, -34.803481 ], [ -56.184004, -34.803634 ], [ -56.184004, -34.803801 ], [ -56.184294, -34.804156 ], [ -56.184521, -34.804412 ], [ -56.184480, -34.804579 ], [ -56.184244, -34.804810 ], [ -56.184515, -34.804683 ], [ -56.186638, -34.803834 ], [ -56.187090, -34.803630 ], [ -56.189534, -34.802532 ], [ -56.190238, -34.802224 ], [ -56.190814, -34.802614 ], [ -56.191329, -34.802473 ], [ -56.192137, -34.802250 ], [ -56.193638, -34.802313 ], [ -56.194082, -34.802339 ], [ -56.194629, -34.802369 ], [ -56.195271, -34.802863 ], [ -56.196635, -34.803914 ], [ -56.197952, -34.804928 ], [ -56.199705, -34.806275 ], [ -56.200920, -34.807628 ], [ -56.199743, -34.808159 ], [ -56.196550, -34.809629 ], [ -56.196410, -34.809692 ], [ -56.194789, -34.810445 ], [ -56.193912, -34.810840 ], [ -56.193801, -34.810890 ], [ -56.192433, -34.811502 ], [ -56.193586, -34.813175 ], [ -56.193689, -34.813310 ], [ -56.194529, -34.814299 ], [ -56.196246, -34.816552 ], [ -56.198977, -34.815012 ], [ -56.199792, -34.814545 ], [ -56.203145, -34.812625 ], [ -56.203774, -34.812267 ], [ -56.204788, -34.811678 ], [ -56.207258, -34.810278 ], [ -56.208626, -34.809494 ], [ -56.209196, -34.809204 ], [ -56.209616, -34.810785 ], [ -56.209645, -34.810866 ], [ -56.210040, -34.811942 ], [ -56.210613, -34.813423 ], [ -56.210675, -34.813553 ], [ -56.210728, -34.813666 ], [ -56.211571, -34.814934 ], [ -56.212384, -34.816189 ], [ -56.213011, -34.817044 ], [ -56.218728, -34.813542 ], [ -56.219888, -34.812831 ], [ -56.220005, -34.811596 ], [ -56.219779, -34.811304 ], [ -56.220047, -34.811145 ], [ -56.220184, -34.809702 ], [ -56.220210, -34.809495 ], [ -56.220324, -34.808260 ], [ -56.220346, -34.808025 ], [ -56.220314, -34.807809 ], [ -56.220509, -34.807700 ], [ -56.220796, -34.804526 ], [ -56.220894, -34.803440 ], [ -56.220965, -34.802660 ], [ -56.220991, -34.802376 ], [ -56.220795, -34.802489 ], [ -56.220979, -34.800686 ], [ -56.221031, -34.800064 ], [ -56.221130, -34.799049 ], [ -56.221303, -34.798977 ], [ -56.221367, -34.798282 ], [ -56.221540, -34.796195 ], [ -56.221705, -34.795122 ], [ -56.221795, -34.794549 ], [ -56.221844, -34.793977 ], [ -56.221930, -34.792998 ], [ -56.222031, -34.791844 ], [ -56.222149, -34.790501 ], [ -56.222206, -34.789847 ], [ -56.222263, -34.789239 ], [ -56.222496, -34.786705 ], [ -56.223773, -34.786075 ], [ -56.224074, -34.786849 ], [ -56.224027, -34.785948 ], [ -56.223960, -34.784668 ], [ -56.223862, -34.782793 ], [ -56.224299, -34.780673 ], [ -56.224313, -34.780628 ], [ -56.224957, -34.778621 ], [ -56.225598, -34.776618 ], [ -56.225619, -34.776554 ], [ -56.225722, -34.776126 ], [ -56.226253, -34.773929 ], [ -56.226288, -34.773785 ], [ -56.226301, -34.773735 ], [ -56.226850, -34.771651 ], [ -56.227211, -34.770280 ], [ -56.227522, -34.768765 ], [ -56.227649, -34.768147 ], [ -56.227629, -34.767746 ], [ -56.227432, -34.767566 ], [ -56.226401, -34.767434 ], [ -56.225053, -34.766195 ], [ -56.224372, -34.766057 ], [ -56.223837, -34.765603 ], [ -56.223023, -34.765561 ], [ -56.222495, -34.765549 ], [ -56.221846, -34.764487 ], [ -56.221418, -34.763276 ], [ -56.220861, -34.762142 ], [ -56.220051, -34.761780 ], [ -56.219932, -34.759838 ], [ -56.219535, -34.759613 ], [ -56.219424, -34.759551 ], [ -56.217205, -34.755114 ], [ -56.214884, -34.749974 ], [ -56.212206, -34.744168 ], [ -56.211237, -34.742426 ], [ -56.209712, -34.739691 ], [ -56.204933, -34.734387 ], [ -56.205012, -34.733945 ], [ -56.204301, -34.733248 ], [ -56.204165, -34.732762 ], [ -56.204204, -34.732158 ], [ -56.203724, -34.731447 ], [ -56.203463, -34.730889 ], [ -56.203387, -34.730727 ], [ -56.201876, -34.729776 ], [ -56.201374, -34.728921 ], [ -56.197919, -34.726028 ], [ -56.196230, -34.724618 ], [ -56.192507, -34.721807 ], [ -56.181724, -34.721008 ], [ -56.178183, -34.719355 ], [ -56.175364, -34.721355 ], [ -56.172551, -34.725184 ], [ -56.170799, -34.729007 ], [ -56.169928, -34.732326 ], [ -56.165689, -34.733004 ] ] ] } },
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: No conozco la librería que usas, pero ahí lo que te dice es que estás tratando de acceder al atributo 'get' de un objeto que no has instanciado, en otras palabras, el objeto al que tratas de acceder no existe en el momento en el que lo llamas.

Comment: Más que no existir, tiene el valor `None`. Alguna función has llamado esperando que te retornase un diccionario, pero la función retornó en cambio `None`. Cuando intentas hacer `.get()` sobre esa variable obtienes el error mencionado. Debes examinar mejor el mensaje de error completo, pues te dirá en qué línea ocurrió y qué variable era la que se estaba usando en ese momento. Revisa entonces cómo se asigna esa variable para descubrir cuándo recibe el valor `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Deben coincidir los valores del campo inicial en columns (Neighborhood) y los valores del key_on (features.properties.id_barrio). En su caso el error es porque en el dataset (mvd_merged_final) no existe clave con el campo que indica (Neighborhood). También debe existir el campo de valor numérico (Avg Usd/m2). Ejemplo:

mvd_map.choropleth(
...
columns=['id_barrio', 'Avg Usd/m2'],
key_on = 'features.properties.id_barrio',
...
)...